# Trello api to update description section?

Tags: php, curl, codeigniter-3, trello

I am looking for the API to update trello board "Description" part. 
I have gone through this [API doc](https://developers.trello.com/reference)

I couldn't able to find out the same. Please help me to get the work done. 
I am attaching the screenshot of the trello description section for better clarity.[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that a "Card", or something else? https://developers.trello.com/reference#cardsid-1 seems likely if so.

Comment: This is a card only.. There is a test board and this is one of the card in that..

Comment: Right, so the link I gave is the correct document showing how to update cards, including descriptions.

Comment: Yes, I have also mentioned the same link in question. But can u please tell me where we can find the portion to update that highlighted description part.

Comment: I did. There's an anchor in the URL that will take you to the correct part. Or search for `/cards/{id}`.

Comment: Yeah, i got it. So there we can only change the description, right ? So it will not affect rest of the data... correct?

Comment: Um.. no? You can update lots of things if that's what you send. Looking at it you can choose to only send the fields you want to update, but it's not an endpoint JUST to update description. If that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you so much @JonStirling ... will try this and will come back again!